# SharePoint Search permissions for users and admins

Tags: search, permissions, search-results

I am using SharePoint 2010. I have created some sub sites and given permissions as admin to some of them. If end-user log in, it should not display secured pages in search results. If admin log ins and then only the secured pages should be shown in search results.

Now, whenever I use SharePoint search with end-user login (not as admin), this search displays results page of secured admin pages also. I want these secured pages to be shown in search results only if admin logins. If end-user logins, other pages with no admin permissions should be shown only.

What is the problem? What should be done?

Answer (score 3):

Sharepoint search inherits from the same permission structure as other items. So that means; if an item is not viewable by a user, then it will not be available through this user's search also.

Results to be shown depends directly on the permissions of the items' permissions to be shown.
I guess you should do a re-crawl for the search, then observe the results again.

You should keep in mind that, if you want your pages to be shown only to admin(btw you need to be clear on the admin word, is it "system account" or some user group that includes users with high privileges); then this page's permission must also tell you that it will be not viewable except that user (and must also not viewable by anonymous users).

You should check that: [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010general/thread/82af0cf2-ca5b-4009-87ff-c6cf02414f43/)

Comment: If permissions change do you have to do a re-crawl for those to be in effect?

Comment: It's a good question, I don't know that. I suggested the recrawl operation in case of the "secured page" he mentioned is not in the search results because of a lack of crawl not the permission!

Comment: Yeah I hear ya. I think another crawl is required. i did a quick test (denied a folder to myself) but I could still make the contents of that folder show up in search. after a crawl they disappeared.